# Getting undefined word on the attributes of User in AWS Amplify in Readct

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I'm using @aws-amplify/ui-react to add custom funcionality on the ForceNewPassword of Cognito

I'm trying to add the phone number on the ForceNewPassword component but when the request is send I always get an undefined value on the usser attributes. I don't know why is getting that by default always

[image]

[image]